# Map view leaflet on SilverStripe

Tags: leaflet, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I work on SilverStripe 4 using leaflet and my cards present these gray lines:

[image]

I tried a lot of stuff on CSS and JS but no change. Can someone advise how to supress these gray lines?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the photo you mentioned.

Comment: did you include leaflet.css ?

Comment: the photo is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef9Ud.png

Comment: Yeah i perfectly include the .css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grey lines are caused by your site css adding a border to your images.

If you inspect the marker `img` element you will see there is some `img` css that adds a border. Something like the following:

```css
img {
    border: 4px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

Here is a demo recreating the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/5jbgyeq0/

A few options to fix the problem are:

1. Remove that css
2. Make the css more specific so it doesn't apply to the map images
3. Add some css to remove borders on map pane images

Here is an example of some css to remove borders on map pane images:

```css
.leaflet-map-pane img {
    border: none;
}
```